# Django Login / Post Login

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm having problems with django's user accounts/login.  I'm trying to do a few things post login but after I login the website is showing that I have not logged in.  For example in the html tag if I use {{ user }} it prints out Anonymous User even if I'm not logged in. I don't know what is wrong with my code:

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to response({'user', request.user})
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^$', 'tickets.views.index'),
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' ),
(r'^accounts/logout/$','django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
```

login.html is basic django login template and on index I have {{ user }} displayed.

Thanks for any help.

edit:

I do have a template tag i just didn't enter it there. I want it to say that I'm logged in after I log in. For example: if i log in with the account test i want test to show up where {{ user }} is not anonymoususer.

Comment: Did you put

    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes'

in your installed apps?

Did you run `syncdb` after doing so?

Comment: Your `render_to_response()` call is missing a template argument.

Comment: This is correct. If you are not logged in, you are in fact `AnonymousUser`

Comment: I do have a template tag i just didn't enter it there. I want it to say that I'm logged in after I log in.  For example: if i log in with the account test i want test to show up where {{ user }} is not anonymoususer.

Comment: if you refresh the page after you login does it still show you are an anonymous user?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check SESSION_ENGINE in your setting. It may be cache backend, and
   cache may be set to dummy.
2. Check that 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Answer (score 0):

I just reread your question. You *should* be getting AnonymousUser when not logged in.

See [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser).

> An anonymous user is one that is not authenticated i.e. they have provided no valid authentication details. However, that does not necessarily mean they are not authorized to do anything. At the most basic level, most Web sites authorize anonymous users to browse most of the site, and many allow anonymous posting of comments etc.

Comment: that's correct, but when I log in I still get anonymoususer which is the current problem I am having.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to do something like this in your template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <p>Hi logged in user!</p>
{% else %}
  <p>Please login</p>
{% endif %}
```

When the user hasn't logged in you will get an instance of [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser). You can check to see if they are authenticated by calling the `is_authenticated()` method.